# How to catch row reorder event in primeng table?

Tags: primeng, primeng-datatable

I want to trigger a reorder event after I drag and drop two rows data but I cannot see it in the document below:
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/reorder
Can anyone help me, thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As per the documentation ,

there are two callbacks available ,

onColReorder - Callback to invoke when a column is reordered

onRowReorder - Callback to invoke when a row is reordered.

They are listed under on the events portion on the same page

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table

Answer (score 3):

For those wondering where to bind the `onRowReorder` callback to catch row reorder event.

app.component.html:

```
<p-table [value]="products" (onRowReorder)="onRowReorder($event)">

...

</p-table>
```

app.component.ts:

```
onRowReorder(event){
  console.log(event); //{dragIndex: 1, dropIndex: 2}
}
```

[View in StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablereorder-demo-fhvwjp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html&file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)